# Is super.clone() of Cloneable a thread safe method?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a class `Foo`

```
public class Foo implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    public Foo() {}
    protected String s;
    protected int n;
    public Foo clone()  {
        return (Foo) super.clone();
    }
    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public String getN() {
        return n;
    }
    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}
```

And it's used in `MyClass` and the handler is passed to two thread `A` and `B` what appens if at the same time thread A try to clone the handler and thread B try to change a public variable of the handler?
E.g.

```
Foo Class
    s = "Hello"
    n = "42"
```

This class is passed to `A` and `B` that run at the same time.
`A` wants clone `Foo Class` and after 1 µs `B` wants change n to `43`.
The clone result will be `s = "Hello" and n = "42" || n = "43"`?
More simpler: `super.clone()` is thread safe or I have to use `lock` or `synchronized`? In case I have to use `lock` or `synchronized` which is the best way to use them?

Comment: Why do you *have* public variables? That's the real problem. Provide synchronized setters and the problem disappears, not just for cloning but for everything.

Comment: `protected` is no better than `public`.  If you make the variables `protected`, then I can write code that accesses or changes them without respect for your synchronization, and without calling any of your methods.  Only `private` stops other programmers from doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are slightly misusing the term "thread-safe". It does not mean "synchronized", and that's apparently how you are using it. No amount of synchronization can prevent implementation errors from breaking thread safety. As an example, any code you wrote which mutates the object while not holding any lock will clearly violate thread safety of the object, and there is nothing a library method like `Object.clone` can do about that.

Ultimately, thread safety is always in the hands of the implementor and `Object.clone()` will not do anything to make that harder for you: all it does is read the state of the current object and copy it to the new object. It does not publish that new object.

Comment: I'm new to Java and thanks very much for your answer. Which could be a possible solution? Add to synchronized to setters?

Comment: Even if you make your `clone` method and all setters `synchronized` you don’t have any guaranty that the `clone` operation will be performed before the setter. The only guaranty that you have then is that they are not performed at the same time and thus don’t interfere (which isn’t that important for `int` and `String` properties). But multi-threading doesn’t give you any predictable timing. On the other hand, if you use one of the *working* solutions for establishing a timing relationship, these solutions will already imply a form of synchronization.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: that’s the big problem. You have the guaranty that you will see the result of an action about which you don’t know whether it actually happened, *if* it happened. So it’s completely worthless. And if you cared about visibility you had mentioned that, of course, the *getters* have to be `synchronized` as well…

Comment: @Holger Not sure what you mean there. If all the setters and clone are synchronized you're guaranteed to get a clone of the instance at one particular point in time - that's hardly worthless and generally all you need (if you have special requirements you'll have to synchronize accordingly)

Comment: @Voo And not just all you need: all you can *hope for*.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: just read the question carefully. The OP think there is a scenario where thread “`A` wants clone `Foo Class` and after 1 µs `B` wants change n to `43`”. Since Java doesn’t guaranty that thread `A` will ever *start* it’s call to `clone` within 1 µs, there is no guaranty the thread `B`’s call to modify `n` happens after `A`’s `clone`. Making the methods `synchronized` doesn’t fix the mistake of thinking that you can predict thread activities on a µs granularity (or any time basis).

Comment: @Voo: you *always* have the guaranty “to get a clone of the instance at one particular point in time”; that’s the “no values out of thin air” guaranty. If you want consistency across multiple property values, a class having multiple setters can’t guaranty that; it requires measures taken by the calling threads. Thus, what the OP wants *is* a “special requirement”; the OP wants a guaranty that `B`’s call to `setN(43)` happens after `A`’s call to `clone` and simply making the methods `synchronized` can’t provide that.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: Without that requirement it would degrade to the question “Am I guaranteed to see either `42` or `43`” which can be answered with “yes” even without synchronization. Without enforcing memory visibility, it’s more likely to see `42` but that’s still “either `42` or `43`”. But I’m afraid that a questioner presenting us an all-unsynchronized class and asking for thread-safety for the specific action of `clone` only, is very likely to have problems that can’t be solved by simply recommending to just make all method `synchronized`…

Comment: @Holger Without synchronized you actually can get a copy of the instance that never existed in the other line of execution (reordering of writes, visibility, also split access for long/double is pretty much out of thin air value). But yeah I'm with Marko on that - I don't think the op meant the question in that way.

Comment: @Tinwor, FYI: the whole point of this dialogue is that "thread safety" is not composeable.  That is to say, even if all of the classes that you use in your program are "thread safe", that will not make your _program_ thread safe.  Your original question basically asks, "how can I implement the Foo class so that the program that uses it will be thread safe?"  And the answer is, you can't.  If we say that class Foo is "thread safe," the most that can ever mean is that overlapped Foo method calls won't screw up the state of any _single_ Foo instance.

Answer (score 1):

`clone` is not specifically described as thread-safe, which means it's not. If one thread is cloning the object while another thread is changing it, the clone can end up in an inconsistent state.

You could grab a lock in your `clone` function, but much better would be to grab it in the code which calls `clone`.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not thread safe if two threads are trying to execute this method over the same instance of Foo.

You should create a mutex using this instance .For example place the code which executes this clone method in synchronized(fooInstance) block.